# SQL Using Trigger To Populate New Table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

Hey all so I have created a table called ProductsAudit that looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductsAudit
(
 AuditID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 ProductID INT NOT NULL,
 CategoryID INT NULL,
 ProductCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 ProductName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 ListPrice MONEY NOT NULL,
 DiscountPercent MONEY NOT NULL,
 DateUpdated DATETIME NULL
);
```

ProductsAudit table is nearly identical to another table called Products:

```
ProductID (PK, int, NOT NULL)
CategoryID (FK, int, NULL)
ProductCode (varchar(10), NOT NULL)
ProductName(varchar(255), NOT NULL)
Description(Text, NOT NULL)
ListPrice(money, NOT NULL)
DiscountPercent(money, NOT NULL)
DateAdded(datetime, NULL)
```

Next I have created a trigger called Products_UPDATE which should insert data from the Products table into the ProductsAudit table after a row in Products is updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE
ON Products
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO ProductsAudit (AuditID, ProductID, CategoryID, ProductCode, 
                      ProductName, ListPrice, DiscountPercent, DateUpdated)
    SELECT  
      i.ProductID, i.ProductID, i.CategoryID, i.ProductCode, 
      i.ProductName, i.ListPrice, i.DiscountPercent, i.DateAdded
  FROM inserted i
  JOIN ProductsAudit pa ON pa.ProductID = i.ProductID
```

Now, I assume I am constructing my trigger incorrectly because it appears to not be working. For example I can update my products table like so:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS
SET ProductCode = 'ABC1233'
WHERE ProductID = 18;
SELECT * FROM Products;
SELECT * FROM ProductsAudit;
```

The row in Products is updating correctly however I am not getting any data inserted into the ProductsAudit table.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your query is joining to ProductsAudit as part of the insert. Not really sure what you are trying to do but is probably the issue. Also, you really should change your text datatype to varchar(max). Or even a reasonable varchar size. Text has been deprecated for 10 years now and should not be used.

Comment: This trigger laguage may not work at all in mysql.  Triggers are very database specific.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you joining with "ProductsAudit" in your trigger? that's causing the issue here.

Comment: This was my issue, thanks! I misunderstood what I was trying to accomplish, I thought it was necessary to join where ID's would match.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
      i.ProductID, i.ProductID, i.CategoryID, i.ProductCode, 
      i.ProductName, i.ListPrice, i.DiscountPercent, i.DateAdded
  FROM inserted i
  JOIN ProductsAudit pa ON pa.ProductID = i.ProductID
```

This would insert a record only if the product id already existed in the audit table.

Personally I would also add a column to tell you which user made the change. If things are going wroong it is helpful to know what user or application caused the problem.

Also why is the data for AuditID, ProductID the same? What is the point of having two fields?

Answer (score 0):

do you commit ? If you dont, you probably cant see the audit. as you can rollback or commmit? what db are you using ?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio. I don't think I need to commit, I may be wrong though.